# mod_rewrite rewrite folder to domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Hi I have two domains running on the same Apache server.

What I would like to do is rewrite `www.domain1.com\folder` to `domain2.domain1.com` .

I have have put this in the `.htaccess` file in `\folder` dirctory.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . http://domain2.domain.com/ [L]
```

However this redirects the page to domain and not rewrites it.

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite assumes the redirection is external because the target is not the same virtualhost, it is external and rewrite internally does not apply for "external targets" what you really need is to reverse proxy, change the rewrite to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain2.domain.com$1 [P,L]
```

With the P flag for Reverse Proxy. (note that you will need mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http modules loaded.

Comment: Thanks, but that still redirects and not rewrites, I want the `www.domain1.com\folder` to show content from `domain2.domain1.com` with the url staying the same.

Comment: I see, what really happens is that mod_rewrite is seeing the target is external and rewriting the url anyways, even if you didn't specify external redirection, because internal redirection for external target does not make sense, it is reverse proxy. Let me fix the answer.

Comment: Nope still redirecting. Is there another way to do this, both the urls share the same main domain?

Comment: P flag never redirects. So you are experiencing other configuration from somewhere else, or I don't understand what you understand by "redirecting".

Comment: I mean like a standard rewrite where by the url stays the same, so location reads `www.domain1.com\folder` but content comes from `domain2.domain1.com` .

Comment: Try my last modification. If this does not work for you, review your config as something is interfering with this rewrite.

Comment: Sorry, got that due to a spelling mistake I am now getting : `400 Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand:`

Comment: Ok, I have added a trailing slash, but this now loads www.domain1.com .

Comment: There are clearly other directives going on you didn't show.